# QLocalSocket connect to non-Qt server socket on linux

Tags: c++, c, linux, qt, sockets

I have a non-Qt server socket, I want to create Qt client socket (using QLocalSocket) and connect this client to non-Qt server socket. But client cannot find server.

Here is the server

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int server_sockfd, client_sockfd;
    sockaddr_un server_address;
    sockaddr_un client_address;
    int client_len;
    int res, connect;

    /* remove old socket and create unnamed socket */
    unlink("server_socket");
    server_sockfd = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    /* non-blocking socket */
    //fcntl(server_sockfd, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);

    /* name the socket */
    server_address.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
    strcpy(server_address.sun_path, "server_socket");
    bind(server_sockfd, (sockaddr*)&server_address, sizeof(server_address));

    /* listen client */
    printf("server_waiting\n");
    listen(server_sockfd, 5);
    client_len = sizeof(client_address);

    client_sockfd = accept(server_sockfd, (sockaddr*) &client_address, (socklen_t*) &client_len);
    fcntl(client_sockfd, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);


    while(1) {
        char ch;
        res = recv(client_sockfd, &ch, 1, 0);
        if (res == -1) {
            sleep(1);
            printf("not_received_data_from_client\n");
        }
        else if(res == 0) {
            sleep(1);
            printf("client_shutdowned\n");
        }
        else {
            printf("received: %c\n", ch);
        }
    }

}
```

And i use Qt client example [Local Fortune Client Example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcore-ipc-localfortuneclient-example.html)

Thank you.

Comment: For starters, the code you posted is C, but you have labeled both C and C++, which language does your question concern. (delete the tag that is inappropriate) Which Qt? 3, 4, FW5? (your link is to Qt5, so we can presume that)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin The author is using c on the server side, and c ++ (Qt) on the client side.

Comment: @David C. Rankin. I am using C on server linux, and C++ on qt client.

Comment: You are missing the `struct` keyword in `struct sockaddr_un server_address, client_address;`, `(struct sockaddr*)`, and I presume you `#include <sys/un.h>` for the `un` members given `server_address.sun_family = AF_UNIX;`

Comment: @David C. Rankin. I just post main code of server, I included all header in my code, and the server runs ok with a C client, but with Qt client it is not ok

Comment: OK, that makes more sense, I guess you `typedef` in your header. It's hard to tell without a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Are you sure you're using the correct server path name in the `Qt` client?

Comment: @G.M. yes, I pass "server_socket" to textbox in Qt client

Comment: Try making the socket path absolute for both the server and client: e.g. "/tmp/server_socket".  I suspect the problem might be the location of the file system entry associated with the socket.

Comment: @G.M. Thank you a lot, It is solved.